# Does dreams make sense?

Tags: the-buddha, lay-buddhism

I've watched on t.v that a monk had dreamt that Lama told him a lady will come to monastery and will request him let her with them when this was only for monks though he going to let her with them and teach Dhamma. Next day it happens what he had dreamt about; first he disagreed but later on he remembered his dream last night he had and then she became nun. So does dreams making sense ? I had one on full moon day that I'm crying next Buddha's statue in vihara saying give me power and peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.Dreams sometimes makes sense sometimes they don't.It's not an isolated event people  sometimes experience dreams that do take place in the future.And it's getting harder to just dismiss it as mere coincidence [(Precognitive Dreams)](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2011/mar/01/precognitive-dreaming-dismissed-science).This is just a natural functioning of the mind.Whether dreams makes sense or not is not what releases us from suffering.

Comment: Sometimes dreams are just garbage stuff of our mind and sometimes they being unexpected and speechless.

Comment: I have experienced if a say "Aum" (long & loud) for couple of minutes before sleep, i don't see dreams.

Buddha also says what we think we become..)

Answer (score 0):

When we are in deep sleep our mind (chitt) doesn't get prana from self(soul, energy) and in result we do not remember anything, just nothingness.

But as soon as we are not in deep sleep, our chitt (which actually has the memory of each and every past lives), which in result gives us Dejavu.

The paradoxical point now is a blind man never saw dreams, a deaf being would never listen in dream(he will only see).

I think it also depends on our perception, i have seen a girl who can see with closed eyes.